# NGINX gives error on Centos 7 with PHP 5.6

Tags: nginx, php

I tried everything on the internet to get PHP 5.6 to work on Centos 7 with NGINX. I do not want PHP 5.4 (This works) because it's outdated as hell. Currently, NGINX gives me the following error when I visit a php page on my website (502 bad gateaway):

> *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

I am desperate for help and explanation.

I got the following set in /etc/php-fpm.d:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

And I have this set in php.ini:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

This is my config for NGINX:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
include blacklisted_ips.conf; include cloudflare_settings.conf;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_body_buffer_size      128k;
    client_max_body_size         10m;
    client_header_buffer_size    1k;
    large_client_header_buffers  4 4k;
    output_buffers               1 32k;
    postpone_output              1460;
    client_header_timeout  3m;
    client_body_timeout    3m;
    send_timeout           3m;
    open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_types text/html application/x-javascript text/css application/javascript text/javascript text/plain text/xml application/json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-opentype application/x-font-truetype application/x-font-ttf application/xml font/eot font/opentype font/otf image/svg+xml image/vnd.microsoft.icon;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 http2 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
        server_name  clubpenguinlite.pw www.clubpenguinlite.pw;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        server_tokens off;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 5s;
        # Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
        # the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

       location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your nginx and php-fpm error logs look like?

Comment: My guess is the PHP-FPM configuration isn't correct. PHP error logs key, particularly correlating entries with the Nginx error log entries.